# JS is not triggering when a user is not logged in odoo 13

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-website

I was developing an odoo theme but for some reason my js is not triggering when a user is not logged in

```
odoo.define('n_theme.jq_website', function (require) {
'use strict';

     alert('on_website');

     $(".nav.navbar-nav").after('<ul class="nav_right ml-auto text-right"> </ul>');

     $(".nav-item.dropdown").detach().appendTo($('.nav_right'));
     $(".nav-item.dropdown").after('<ul class="trial"> 14 days</ul>');
     $(".nav.navbar-nav").removeClass('ml-auto text-right');
     $(".nav.navbar-nav").addClass('offcanvas-collapse');
    
     $(".navbar-toggler.collapsed").data('toggle','offcanvas');



})
```

I figured out why my JS was not working and I was using the wrong inherit_id xml

#Wrong **inherit_id="website.assets_editor"**

```
  <template id="myscript" name="My script" inherit_id="website.assets_editor">
    <xpath expr="script[last()]" position="after">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/n_theme/static/js/script.js"/>
    </xpath>
  </template>
```

the correct one is **inherit_id="website.assets_frontend"**

I am not sure if I should delete the question it is so stupid

Comment: You should not deleted the question  stupid things are what takes a lot of time to figure out : )